# How do I reduce the number of constructor parameters in controllers and business layer services?

Tags: c#, architecture, mediator, business-logic-layer, domainservices

This is a re-wording of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334641/should-i-use-the-mediator-pattern-to-communicate-between-the-service-business-la).

I found that using the mediator pattern is effective at reducing the number of parameters in my controllers.

I then began to wonder if this would be affective domain services.

But wouldn't that hide the dependencies of the service?

I remember reading somewhere that if I have a bunch of dependencies being injected, I probably have a larger domain concept that can be encapsulated in its own service. I found this to be an effective pattern.

So, how do I reduce the number of constructor parameters in the business layer services?

Comment: @theDmi Reworded, hopefully I can get some community insight on this one ;)

Comment: You should have edited your original question. It's already on the way to being reopened and a significant edit like this would only help speed that along.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too many constructor parameters are a code smell and typically indicate a **violation of the *single responsibility principle*** - so you need to take care of that "S" in your SOLID code base.

A constructor parameter is a dependency. By "solving" the problem with a mediator, you will still have the same number of dependencies, just with fewer constructor parameters. You essentially move from a visible SRP code smell to a hidden SRP code smell - not really a step forward.

#### Improving "too many dependencies" situations

[This blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) talks about this exact problem and supports it with an example.

The basic approach to improve your situation is to find code that clusters around a set of dependencies and extract that code into a new service class:

> 1. Analyze how dependencies interact to identify clusters of behavior.
> 2. Extract an interface from these clusters.
> 3. Copy the original implementation to a class that implements the new interface.
> 4. Inject the new interface into the consumer.
> 5. Replace the original implementation with a call the new dependency.
> 6. Remove the redundant dependencies.

Comment: I agree with this logic.  That being said, can't we apply this to API controllers as well?  Perhaps we need to breakup the concerns of a our api controllers into more specific controller classes?

Comment: The process of breaking up the concerns and their boundaries can be challenging. As a guide, you can use business terminology and business capabilities.

Comment: @drizzie These steps can be applied to any class with too many constructor parameters, even value objects! The only thing that differs is how you name the extracted concept.